# Comments system : Hstore with normal association VS simple attributes with polymorfic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I would create a small social network to share photos and videos and also events:

photos table attributes are : `title, description, name`

videos table attributes are : `title , description , name, runtime`

events table attributes are : `title, description, date_begining, date_end`

as you can see there is some duplication between the tree tables, but this is not a important at all.

so each model (Photo, Video, Event) should have possibility to add **comments**, i'm using **Postgresql** and the simple way to do this is to use **Polymorfic Association**, But i think also that i can use **hstore** and treat all of them (photo, video, event) like a single model (for example Share) which contains the common attributes and add a properties column to Shares table :

```
Shares ( title:string, description:string, name:string, properties:hstore)
```

with that, i think i don't need any *polymorfic association* , and i can add a simple relation between `Share` and `Comment` models like this :

```
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :share
end
```

My question here is what is the **best** method to do this (faster + performance) ? and if i use Hstore, there is a possibility that i find problems in the future if i would change or migrate to another database management system ?

Comment: I would like to see some benchmarks regarding performance as well.

I've seen some discussions where a REALLY LARGE SET of comments would perform better if stored as HStore, but I don't have the source anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hstore is better for hash like data to provide you great flexibilities on attributes.

For simple use case of comment with fixed attributes(no more than body, title, user, commentable?), I don't think it's necessary.

Setting association is as simple as

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many comments, as: :commentable
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many comments, as: :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable.

I'm not sure if you can query within hstore, but in general, keeping the `Comment` as a an ActiveRecord model might be more convenient. (think about associations, querying and all the other Activerecord stuff you get as opposed to using HStore.)